# On fractional parts and Behrend’s construction

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, diophantine-approximation

Given $\theta \in \Bbb{T}^D := \Bbb{R}^D/\Bbb{Z}^D$, write $f_\theta$ for the homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}\to \Bbb{T}^D$ induced by $1\mapsto \theta$.

For $x\in \Bbb{T}^D$, let $||x||$ be the smallest $\delta \ge 0$ such that $x \in [-\delta,\delta]^D+\Bbb{Z}^D$.

Given $\theta\in \Bbb{T}^D$, let $$F_\theta(N) := \#(n\in \{1,\dots,N\}: ||f_\theta(n)|| < 1/4),$$
$$\delta_\theta(N) := \min_{n\in \{1,\dots,N\}} \{||f_\theta(n)||\}.$$Finally, let $\sigma_D(N) := \max_{\theta \in \Bbb{T}^D}\{\sqrt{\delta_\theta(N)}F_\theta(N)\}$ and $$\sigma(N) := \max_D\{\frac{\sigma_D(N)}{D}\}.$$

My question is: what are some upper bounds for $\sigma_D(N)$ and $\sigma(N)$? Ambitiously, it would be very nice to show $\sigma(N) \le N \exp(-c \sqrt{\log N})$ for some absolute constant $c>0$.

**Edit:**

It occurs to me that $\sigma_{D+1}(N)\le \sigma_D(N)$, since you can isometrically embed $\Bbb{T}^D\hookrightarrow \Bbb{T}^{D+1}$ by appending a zero to the last coordinate.

I also realize that we probably also have that $\sigma_D(N)\le N\exp(-c\sqrt{\log N})$ for all $D,N\ge 1$ (meaning that the "$1/D$" factor in the definition of $\sigma(N)$ may be a minor red herring).

**Motivation and further discussion:**

Behrend’s construction tells us that given $N\ge 1$ and $\theta \in\Bbb{T}^D$, there exists a $3$-AP-free set $A \subset \{1,\dots,N\}$ with $|A|\ge \Omega(\sqrt{\delta_\theta(N)}F_\theta(N)/D)$. By definition of $\sigma$, we can find such an $A$ with $|A|\ge c\sigma(N)$ (for some absolute constant $c>0$).

If one fixes $N$ and considers a random $\theta \in \Bbb{T}^D$, we typically have that $F_\theta(N) \sim N/2^D$ and $\delta_\theta(N) \ge cN^{-1/D}$ for some $c>0$. Choosing $D$ appropriately with respect to $N$, the discussion above yields the best known lower bounds on the size of $3$-AP-free sets (up to a polylogarithmic factor of $N$). Hence, it seems prudent to ask if one can pick $\theta$ carefully and do better.

Notably, an application of pigeonhole (a la Dirichlet’s Approximation theorem) tells us that $\delta_\theta(N)\le N^{-1/D}$. Thus there isn’t significant room for improvement here.

On the other hand, there are choices for $\theta\in \Bbb{T}^D$ where $F_\theta(N)$ is noticeably larger than $N/2^D$ (the most extreme case being when $\theta=0$). So to control $\sigma(N)$, one must show that such choices of $\theta$ cause $\delta_\theta(N)$ to be much smaller than usual. It feels like the approximate additive structure of the image $f_\theta(\{1,\dots,N\})$ along with its unusual concentration in $\Bbb{T}^D$ should imply the image correlates with some smaller subgroup of $\Bbb{T}^D$ (which presumably would allow us to get a better bound with pigeonhole), but the details elude me.